# Customizing Google + Share Text (snippet)

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-plus

I'm creating an online HTML5/Javascript Quiz. I'm sharing the results of the Quiz through Facebook and Twitter. The messaging is created via Javascript, "I just got X out of Y questions correct"

I want to do the same with Google Plus. However, it appears that the "snippet" is generated by the schema.org, Open Graph, or Title/Description tags on the page. Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/

I thought I could just dynamically generate these tags via query string parameters in PHP, but it looks like Google caches the page. Any ideas?

PHP:

```
<?php 
$correct = strval($_GET['correct']);
$title = "I took the Quiz and answered " . $correct . " of 9 questions correctly.";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo($title); ?></title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo($title); ?>" />
    </head>
</html>
```

I dynamically create the url .../share.php?correct=4

But when I share the page, I see the message:

```
I took the Quiz and answered of 9 questions correctly.
```

It doesn't appear to be displaying the dynamic data. I'm assuming because Google has cached the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The +1 button and share dialogs do use caching. The snippet fetcher is supposed to respect cache-control directives though, so you should be able to implement what you're going for by providing the necessary headers to prevent caching.

In PHP, the following code sets the headers with the necessary data to prevent caching:

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Something else you could consider doing too, is to insert a randomly generated ID into a query string parameter so that the share URL looks unique to the fetcher each time.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

For the best of my knowledge, the plus one button caches the pages. So do the fb like button.
You may want to try this

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://example.com/share.php?correct=4
```

It does the trick. Hope this helps